# Cypress does not pass a test because of a an uncaught exception message

Tags: cypress

In a cypress test I get the following error message in a test run:

```
ReferenceError
The following error originated from your application code, not from Cypress.

  > check_changed is not defined

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your application it will automatically fail the current test.

This behavior is configurable, and you can choose to turn this off by listening to the uncaught:exception
```

Before starting the test steps in the script I use the following snippet:

```
Cypress.once('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
            return false;
          })
```

I do not use a variable with the name `check_changed`.

No idea what causes the error respectively how to avoid this. Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide some documentation on `Cypress.once()`? I'm familiar with `Cypress.on` and `cy.on()`, but not `.once()`.

Comment: Solved! Thanx for the hint! I do not find anything on `Cypress.once()` in the documentation neither. No idea how it came to my mind. Maybe some forum example? It is in deed like this: `Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
            return false;
        })`

Answer (score 2):

`Cypress.once()` is valid syntax, refer to [Binding Events](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/catalog-of-events#Binding-to-Events)

> Both the global Cypress and cy objects are standard Node event emitters. That means you can use the following methods to bind and unbind from events.
>
> - on
> - **once**
> - removeListener
> - removeAllListeners

The reason you are still getting the error after using it, most likely the application is throwing the error *more than once*.

You should also check the browser `devtools` console to see the error, and adjust the failure in the application.

Comment: Interesting! I was searching for `Cypress.once()` which doesn't appear exactly as that in the documentation, and I was unfamiliar with it. Great answer!